# How to solve this ODE? $\frac{y}{x^2}+2+\frac{1}{x}(1+\ln(xy))y'=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac{y}{x^2}+2+\frac{1}{x}(1+\ln(xy))y'=0$$

I tried different methods but couldn't find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: What methods have you tried. Show that you did some work at least.

Comment: Exact, tried to make it exact, it is not linear, can't apply bernoulli, not homogenous and not separable... That's all I know right now.

Comment: write it as $ln(xy)=... $ and take derivative to eliminate $ln$

Answer (score 1):

If you multiply through by $x$, it becomes exact.